# Plotting 3xN matrix(N number of 3D points) on same graph using matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, 3d, plot

I've a `3xN` matrix `W` where  `N` is `50`

`W(1,1)` is `x` coordinate of a point
`W(2,1)` is `y` coordinate of same point
`W(3,1)` is `z` coordinate of same point

Similarly:
`W(1,2)` is `x` coordinate of another point
`W(2,2)` is `y` coordinate of same point
`W(3,2)` is `z` coordinate of same point

....

Now I want to 3d plot all these 3d points  on same figure using matlab. How can I plot all these
points on same figure?

Is it possible to plot this matrix using a single function call(in matlab)?

I know that plot3 can be used but it can be used for one graph at a time.

So `plot3(v(1,1),v(1,2),v(1,3));` is just a single point. But how do I plot all N points?

Is there an easier and better method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use `plot3(w(1,:),w(2,:),w(3,:))`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your suggestion but sorry to say that it draws a line in between points. I don't want any line. I just like to point plot all N number of points on same graph as individual points. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Found the solution. Just have to use scatter3(w(1,:),w(2,:),w(3,:)); Thanks YBE for part of the solution